# Ways to get the liveness of API Server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks

I would like to monitor the liveness of API server in AKS, what standard metrics can be used for it?
I don't see there is a metric directly describe the liveness of API Server, but I am thinking a workaround of using metric **apiserver_request_total**. Its description is **Counter of apiserver requests broken out for each verb, dry run value, group, version, resource, scope, component, and HTTP response code**. Could I write a query, in the last 5mins, count the total number of failed requests(the status code is not 2XX) and compare with the total number of requests, set a threshold like if total number of apiserver failed requests/the total number of apiserver requests is 100%, then the API server's is consider as not alive.
One thing I am not sure is if the API Server is down, is it possible to still get this **apiserver_request_total** metric from prometheus or the metric scraped shows all requests have a failed status code?

In addition, I know k8s provides API health endpoints to check the liveness or healthness of API server as in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/health-checks/ However, it seems designed to used by human not machine(programmatically) as it mentioned.

Another thing I am thinking is use Prometheus query as below as an indictor of if the api server is alive, if the resulting value is 0, means it is unavailable and if it is 1 means api server is alive.

```
 up{job="kube-apiserver"}
```

Comment: First thing you need NOT monitor the API server as it is managed AKS cluster;
You can use Prometheus query and all those metrics should help you out, I think you can also try aggregator_unavailable_apiservice_total metric.

Comment: Why I should Not monitor API server as it is managed AKS cluster? Could you please elaborate on it?